# Extending existing hybris cronjob to send custom result through email

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a `AbstractJobPerformable`, which is an import job. The job itself works great, but sometimes it fails.

I saved the error entries into a List, but I don't know how to extend the Job itself to send me the list troguh email.

Comment: I believe you are talking about Impex import-export job , if yes then it's better to override
ImpExWorker class  --->perform method then do your customization.

Comment: No it is not. We download multiple CSV (not impex) from a FTP and implemented our own importer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `AbstractJobPerformable` is *not* an import job.
Its an `abstract` class that is extended for writing cronjob logic.
To send an email from the `perform()` method of cronjob you put all your code in one big `try{}` block and send an email in `finally{} or catch{}` block of Exception.

```
@Override
public PerformResult perform(CSVImportCronJobModel csvImportCronJobModel) {
    try {
        //your code
        return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.SUCCESS, CronJobStatus.FINISHED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        emailService.sendEmail(csvImportCronJobModel.getLogs());
        return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.FAILURE, CronJobStatus.FINISHED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes I know. You example is pretty much what I implemented. But I thught I can use the Backoffice configuration for the Job to read the email and email template.